# How to systematically transform columns with systematic new names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with multiple time durations that I would like to transform based on another column's value and make that into a new column with a new name. I have code that works on a single column, but I need to do this over 18 columns. In the example data frame, I have given two iti duration columns named `df$iti_1` and `df$iti_2`. I would like to create new columns that add "_trimmed" to the column name of the original columns. If the values in the original columns, `df$iti_1` and `df$iti_2`, are greater than the `df$cue_time` column, then the values of the new "_trimmed" columns should be equal to the df$cue_time value. If they are less than or equal to the df$cue_time column, then the values in the "_trimmed" columns should be equal to the original columns.

So this is the original data frame:

```
names <- c("id","iti_1","iti_2","cue_time")
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- names

df$id <- seq(1:3)
df$iti_1 <- c(.13,20,16)
df$iti_2 <- c(.56,.11,21)
df$cue_time <- c(.33,.33,.33)


  id iti_1 iti_2 cue_time 
1  1  0.13  0.56     0.33          
2  2 20.00  0.11     0.33         
3  3 16.00 21.00     0.33
```

And this is what I want:

```
 id iti_1 iti_1_trimmed iti_2 iti_2_trimmed cue_time
1  1  0.13          0.13  0.56          0.33     0.33
2  2 20.00          0.33  0.11          0.11     0.33
3  3 16.00          0.33 21.00          0.33     0.33
```

This chunk of code will work for one column at a time:

```
ifelse(df$iti_1 > df$cue_time,
       df$iti_1_trimmed <- df$cue_time,
       df$iti_1_trimmed <- df$iti_1)
```

But I'm looking to be able to do this systematically across columns without needing to manually name each new column.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This `dplyr` approach applies the comparison with the `cue_time` column `across` any indicated columns.

*Edit: Added example with `pmin()` following Robert Hacken's suggestion*

##### Setup

```r
library(dplyr)

names <- c("id","iti_1","iti_2","cue_time")
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- names

df$id <- seq(1:3)
df$iti_1 <- c(.13,20,16)
df$iti_2 <- c(.56,.11,21)
df$cue_time <- c(.33,.33,.33)
```

##### Select lowest value with `pmin()`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = starts_with('iti'),
    .fns = ~pmin(., cue_time),
    .names = "{.col}_trimmed"))
#>   id iti_1 iti_2 cue_time iti_1_trimmed iti_2_trimmed
#> 1  1  0.13  0.56     0.33          0.13          0.33
#> 2  2 20.00  0.11     0.33          0.33          0.11
#> 3  3 16.00 21.00     0.33          0.33          0.33
```

##### Or with `if_else`

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(
    .cols = starts_with('iti'),
    .fns = ~if_else(. > cue_time, cue_time, .),
    .names = "{.col}_trimmed"))
#>   id iti_1 iti_2 cue_time iti_1_trimmed iti_2_trimmed
#> 1  1  0.13  0.56     0.33          0.13          0.33
#> 2  2 20.00  0.11     0.33          0.33          0.11
#> 3  3 16.00 21.00     0.33          0.33          0.33
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a for loop and `dplyr` to achieve this.

```
# Original data frame
names <- c("id", "iti_1", "iti_2", "cue_time")
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 3))
colnames(df) <- names

df$id <- seq(1:3)
df$iti_1 <- c(0.13, 20, 16)
df$iti_2 <- c(0.56, 0.11, 21)
df$cue_time <- c(0.33, 0.33, 0.33)

# Iterate over columns starting from the 2nd column
for (col in names[2:length(names)]) {
  trimmed_col <- paste0(col, "_trimmed")
  df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(!!trimmed_col := ifelse(get(col) > df$cue_time, df$cue_time, get(col)))
}

# Print the result
print(df)
```